# PHP - Laravel - Scout: Auto indexing for externally managed database tables (models)

Tags: laravel, indexing, laravel-scout

is there any possibility to **automatically** indexing externally managed database tables with Laravel Scout.

For example i'm using an Model on an externally database table from Laravel. The attributes will be changed from an sub system. After that Laravel Scout should automatically auto index the new data. 
It checks maybe which entries where updated_at or created_at after the last indexing and indexes the new data.

Maybe already exists any solution for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table is in an external database, I'm assuming that it read only. Running `php artisan scout:import "App\Model"` will just reindex the entire table again.

I have a similar issue. Records will be inserted into the table from an external process. Since I'm using the laravel-scout-postgres package, my table has a column named searchable. If it is null, then I know it is not indexed. In `php artisan tinker` I can run something like `$test = App\Models\MyModel::whereNull('searchable')->searchable();` to get those records indexed. I think I will end up having to write a task/job to do the indexing for new records. Maybe you can identify the recent records in your table and get them indexed in a similar way?